# hardwareAccelerated="true" vs. partial drawing

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I needed days to figure out why `invalidate(Rect dirty)` doesn't set the correct clip on newer devices.

The problem is that `hardwareAccelerated="true"` is set by default.
When I set this `hardwareAccelerated="false"`,
I get my right clip in my `onDraw`.

Now my question is:
What is better for performance:
Use `hardwareAccelerated="false"` and draw only the part of my view which is dirty and run only the code in my onDraw that is needed for this
OR
allow `hardwareAcceleration` and let android draw my entire view over and over again?

I guess this question may be answered for every application individually so I add a screenshot of my app.

[image]

As you can see I draw a calendar and each time a user clicks a entry this should get a red border.

Can you give me any suggestions whats best for this requirement?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: did you try to measure onDraw() time ?

Comment: I don't have this implementaion yet so I can't measure. I tried to gather some recommendations before I start a massive refactoring...
But this seems to be a good resource: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#determining

Comment: this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233830/partial-invalidation-in-custom-android-view-with-hardware-acceleration seems to suggest that you can have both  hwd accel and partial redraws